# Unable to insert data in Listbox of tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, tkinter, mqtt

I'm using "on_message" function which is called in receiveText() function to receive an incoming message from MQTT server.

The message which is being received is getting reflected in the print statement but unable to get insert in the Listbox.

While using the same lines of code, it is getting inserted in sendText() function.

Code:

```
class chat_UI:
    def __init__(self, roots, nameLogin, friendLogin):
        roots.title("Chat window")
        self.nameLogin = nameLogin
        self.friendLogin = friendLogin

        self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(roots)  # To see through previous messages.
        self.msg_list = Listbox(roots, height=30, width=100, yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        self.msg_list.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=1)
        self.scrollbar.grid(sticky = W)
        self.msg_list.grid(sticky = E)
        #self.msg_list.see(END)

        Label(roots, text="Enter Message").grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.entry_field = Entry(roots,width=20)
        self.entry_field.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.sendB = Button(roots, text='Send', command=self.sendText)
        self.sendB.grid(row=2, column = 1, pady=4, sticky=W) 

        t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.recieveText,args=(friendLogin, nameLogin)) 
        t1.start()
        #t1.join()

    def sendText(self):
        nameLogin = self.nameLogin
        friendLogin = self.friendLogin
        self.message = self.entry_field.get()
        #self.msg_list.insert(END, (self.friendLogin + ": " + recMsg))
        self.msg_list.insert(END, (self.nameLogin + ": " + self.message))
        mqtt_connect(nameLogin).publish(("techieChat/" + nameLogin), str(self.message), qos = 0)

    def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
        print("In on messafe fn")
        global recMsg
        recMsg = str(msg.payload)
        print("message in chat_ui on_mesg fn: " + recMsg)
        self.msg_list.insert(END, recMsg)

    def recieveText(self, friendLogin, nameLogin):
        print("message in receive text message: " + recMsg)
        client = mqtt_connect(friendLogin)
        client.subscribe("techieChat/" + friendLogin)
        client.on_message = chat_UI.on_message
```

The chat_UI class is being instantiated from other class

```
self.newWindow = Toplevel(self.roots)
chat_UI(self.newWindow, nameLogin, friendLogin)
```

Comment: What does _"unable to get insert in the Listbox."_ mean? Do you mean you don't get any errors, but the data simply vanishes? Or, do you get an error? If so, what's the error? Usually the error will tell you want the problem is.

Comment: hi @Bryan, I'm not getting any errors, simply the data is not getting inserted. Even I used try-catch while inserting but there was no error and the code didn't enter the catch exception.

Comment: Is `mainloop` running? You don't show anywhere in your code that it's running. Regardless, using threads with tkinter is difficult, and it usually doesn't work to try to access a tkinter widget from any thread other than the one that created the root window.

Comment: Yaah, the main loop is running ---->>>> if __name__ == '__main__':
    roots = Tk()
    b = Signup(roots)
    roots.mainloop()

Comment: The receiveText() function called in threading was also called directly in __init__ function of chat_UI class.  Even then, it's not working.

Comment: Wrap the call to `self.msg_list.insert()` in it's own try/expect block as the MQTT client will catch any errors thrown and hide them

Comment: are you receiving message first?

Comment: Hi @BryanOakley I tried to call receiveText() from __init__() function using thread. Initially, it enters the receive text function and also prints "message in receive text message: sample message but when new incoming messages arrive, it does not print anything.

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari yaah, I'm receiving the messages and the content inside the print statement is also getting printed alonf with the latest received messages,(recMsg).

Comment: @hardillb  it didn't worked

Comment: I want expecting it to fix it, but you should be able to see if the is an error been thrown

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to use a tk label? They can offer variable information like so:

```
        label = tk.Label(textvariable=recMsg)
        label.pack(side="left") #<--- i presume you may want to use grid here
```

Comment: If I use a label, then the last message from the chat would be replaced with new messages. It would not be a good solution